# Can't replace single whitespace with string.Replace()

Tags: c#, regex, string, replace

I have run into a problem I do not understand. I am reading data from a file and have run into a situation where `string.Replace(" ", "<whatever>")` on an entry from the file will not replace the occurence of a single whitespace. I cannot help but to feel there is something very basic that I have missed, since the same kind of string declared as a literal works fine.

A typical line from the file (each entry is separated by a tab):

"2016-feb-08 09:54:00"  "2016-feb-08 17:28:00"  "Short" "227"   "5 170,00"  "+3,90%"    "0,00"

The data from the file is read into an array using `File.ReadAllLines().Split(new[] {"\t" }, StringSplitOptions.None);`.

I then want to clean up the fifth entry for further processing, and this is when I run into the problem:
`entries[4].Replace(" ", string.Empty).Replace("\"", string.Empty);` gives "5 170,00"
`Regex.Replace(entries[4], @"\s+", string.Empty).Replace("\"", string.Empty);` gives "5170,00", which is the result I am looking for.

Running the first `Replace()` on a literal with a single space works fine, so I am curious if the whitespace inside the strings from the file are different somehow? And while the Regex solution works, I really want to know what my "issue" is.

Comment: Can you post here the result of the following command: `string x = string.Join(string.Empty, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(entries[4]).Select(b => b.ToString("x2")))`?

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov The result of the command is "2235c2a03137302c303022".

Comment: Maybe you should clean and rebuild your solution.

Comment: You have `NO-BREAK SPACE (0xc2 0xa0)` symbol between `5` and `1`. Regex `\s` matches it. But if you want to use `string.Replace`, then you have to use it like `entries[4].Replace("\u00a0", string.Empty)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use code like below to check hex values of the character.  A normal space is 0x20 which the value showing between the five and the one in the code you posted.

```
            string input = "2016-feb-08 09:54:00 2016-feb-08 17:28:00 Short 227 5 170,00 +3,90% 0,00";
            byte[] output = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
```

Comment: The bytes for the fitth entry shows that there are two characters between "5" and "1"; "Â" and "' '". I guess the question I need to answer then becomes, how did those get in there instead of a single whitespace. Thanks.